# Unexpected token g in JSON at position 0

Tags: angular

I'm trying send to SpringBoot a excell with angular, but I get error:

```
         <form #fileLoad="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addExcell()">
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file"  #fileInput class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="ngNameFile" accept=".xlsx">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline btn-block">add</button>
         </form>

  addExcell() {
    const fileBrowser = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
    if (fileBrowser.files && fileBrowser.files[0]) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('files', fileBrowser.files[0]);
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/ml/insert', true);
      xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this['status'] === 200) {
          const responseText = this['responseText'];
          const files = JSON.parse(responseText);// I never use files

        } else {

        }
      };
      console.log('asd' , formData);
      xhr.send(formData);
    }
  }
```

ERROR

[image]

You can see the formData before the send.pls I need help I've been there all day with this..

Comment: can you show the content of `responseText` before the `JSON.parse`

Comment: responseText good

Comment: My server get call because I get System.out.println()-> good, but when I show the File en SpringBoot my file is null because my file never go out from Angular

Comment: It looks like there's something wrong with encoding. Are you receiving a json file ? try changing its encoding for one without BOM

Comment: not, not, I get a File .xlsx the input file from html

Answer (score 1):

The error lies in the response that you are sending from the server. When you are trying to parse "good" `JSON.parse("good")`, it says the above error.

Please try returning a valid JSON from the server something like below:-

```
JSON.parse("{\"status\": \"good\"}")
```

or create a `try / catch` block to handle error.